# Badcode error using reportlab with python3.10

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

Sometime application crashes with error.
Using
reportlab : 3.6.12
Python : 3.10

getting badcode and io errors

Due to increase in the number of requests, the application is crashing.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 523, in open_for_read
     return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 463, in open_for_read_by_name
     return open(name,mode)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/rl_safe_eval.py", line 880, in __call__
     raise BadCode('missing global %s' % self.__name__)
 reportlab.lib.rl_safe_eval.BadCode: missing global open

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3215, in parse
     self.feed(text)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 110, in feed
     self.goahead(0)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 170, in goahead
     k = self.parse_starttag(i)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 342, in parse_starttag
     self.handle_startendtag(tag, attrs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 427, in handle_startendtag
     self.handle_endtag(tag)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3251, in handle_endtag
     end()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 2718, in end_img
     defn.image = ImageReader(defn.src)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 655, in __init__
     annotateException('\nfileName=%r identity=%s'%(fileName,self.identity()))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 1176, in annotateException
     rl_reraise(t,t(sep.join((_ for _ in (msg,str(v),postMsg) if _))),b)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 138, in rl_reraise
     raise v.with_traceback(b)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 643, in __init__
     fp = open_for_read(fileName,'b')
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 532, in open_for_read
     raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)
 OSError: 

 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])
```

Code i am using. The main function is run and the we are generating tables using the first two functions which uses images.

```
def getEventLogsWithImages(eventLogs,units):
    if len(eventLogs)>=1:
        eventMessage = []
        for event in eventLogs:
            eventType = event['type'].title() if ('type' in event) else None
            if(eventType != 'Flightmode'):
                eventLevel = event['level'].title() if (
                    'level' in event) else 'N/A'
                eventSetValue = event['setValue'] if ('setValue' in event) else 'N/A'
                # eventSetValue = str(format(event['setValue'],'.2f')) if ('setValue' in event) else 'N/A'
                eventValue = event['data'] if('data' in event) else 'N/A'
                # eventValue = str(format(event['data'],'.2f')) if('data' in event) else 'N/A'
                if(eventType == 'Temperature'):
                    eventValue = temperatureConversion(eventValue,units)
                    eventSetValue = temperatureConversion(eventSetValue, units)
                    temperaturePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'Temperature.png')
                    comparator = '<' if(eventValue < eventSetValue) else '>'
                    eventPara = Paragraph('''<para alignment="CENTER" spaceBefore="2" spaceAfter="2"><img src=%s width="18" height="18" valign="middle"/><font size="8">(%s%s)</font></para>''' % (temperaturePath,comparator,eventSetValue), styles['Normal'])
                    eventMessage.extend([eventPara])
                elif(eventType == 'Light'):
                    lightPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'Light.png')
                    eventPara = Paragraph('''<para alignment="CENTER" spaceAfter="2"><img src=%s width="18" height="18" valign="middle"/></para>'''%(lightPath), styles['Normal'])
                    eventMessage.extend([eventPara])
                elif(eventType == 'Shock'):
                    shockPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'Shock.png')
                    eventPara = Paragraph('''<para alignment="CENTER" spaceAfter="2"><img src=%s width="18" height="18" valign="middle"/></para>'''%(shockPath), styles['Normal'])
                    eventMessage.extend([eventPara])
                elif(eventType == 'Battery'):
                    batteryPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'Battery.png')
                    if(eventLevel == 'Violation'):
                        comparator = '<' if(eventValue < eventSetValue) else '>'
                        eventPara = Paragraph('''<para alignment="CENTER" spaceAfter="2"><img src=%s width="18" height="18" valign="middle"/><font color="red" size="8">%s</font>(%s%s)</para>''' % (
                            batteryPath,str(format(eventValue,'.2f')),comparator,eventSetValue), styles['Normal'])
                        eventMessage.extend([eventPara])
                        
                    elif(eventLevel == 'Warning'):
                        comparator = '<' if(eventValue < eventSetValue) else '>'
                        eventPara = Paragraph('''<para alignment="CENTER" spaceAfter="2"><img src=%s width="18" height="18" valign="middle"/><font size="8" color="toColor('#d46d04')">%s</font>(%s%s)</para>''' % (
                            batteryPath,str(format(eventValue,'.2f')),comparator,eventSetValue), styles['Normal'])
                        eventMessage.extend([eventPara])
                elif(eventType == 'Geofence'):
                    if(eventValue['isInside']):
                        entryGeofencePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'EnteredGeofence.png')
                        eventPara = Paragraph('''<para alignment="CENTER" spaceAfter="2"><img src=%s width="18" height="18" valign="middle"/>%s</para>''' % (entryGeofencePath,
                            eventSetValue['address'] if ('address' in eventSetValue) else 'N/A'), styleN)
                        eventMessage.extend([eventPara])
                    else:
                        exitGeofencePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'ExitedGeofence.png')
                        eventPara = Paragraph('''<para alignment="CENTER" spaceAfter="2"><img src=%s width="18" height="18" valign="middle"/>%s</para>''' % (
                            exitGeofencePath,eventSetValue['address'] if ('address' in eventSetValue) else 'N/A'), styleN)
                        eventMessage.extend([eventPara])
        return eventMessage

def getEventsandPingsTable(reportData,units):
    sectionHeading = '''<para spaceAfter=15 spaceBefore=25><font size=11 color="toColor('#028081')">Events and Pings Table:</font></para>'''
    timeZone= 'UTC'
    if('timeZone' in reportData and reportData['timeZone']):
        timeZone = reportData['timeZone']
    tz = timezone(timeZone)
    UTCtz = timezone('UTC')

    pings = reportData['device']['pings'] if ('device' in reportData and 'pings' in reportData['device']) else []
    eventLogs = reportData['device']['modifiedEventLogs'] if('device' in reportData and 'modifiedEventLogs' in reportData['device']) else []

    unitsText = '%s'% (u"\u00b0F") if (units == 'F') else '%s'% (u"\u00b0C")
    temperaturePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'Temperature.png')
    lightPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'Light.png')
    shockPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'Shock.png')
    batteryPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'Battery.png')
    entryGeofencePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'EnteredGeofence.png')
    exitGeofencePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'ExitedGeofence.png')

    eventsText = Paragraph('''
    <para>
      <b><font size="8">%s</font></b>
      <img src=%s width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">%s</font>
      <img src=%s width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">%s</font>
      <img src=%s width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">%s</font>
      <img src=%s width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">%s</font>
      <img src=%s width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">%s</font>
      <img src=%s width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">%s</font>
    </para>'''%('Event Types',temperaturePath,'Temperature',lightPath, 'Light',shockPath,'Shock',batteryPath, 'Battery', entryGeofencePath,'Entered Geofence',exitGeofencePath,'Exited Geofence'), styles['BodyText'])

    pingsData = [[eventsText],['Time', 'Temp (%s)' % (unitsText), 'Events','Latitude','Longitude','Address']]
    tempViolationMax = None
    tempViolationMin = None
    tempWarningMax = None
    tempWarningMin = None
    if('device' in reportData and 'temperatureProfile' in reportData['device'] and 'violationMax' in reportData['device']['temperatureProfile']):
        tempViolationMax = temperatureConversion(reportData['device']['temperatureProfile']['violationMax'], units)
            

    if('device' in reportData and 'temperatureProfile' in reportData['device'] and 'violationMin' in reportData['device']['temperatureProfile']):
        tempViolationMin = temperatureConversion(reportData['device']['temperatureProfile']['violationMin'], units)

    if('device' in reportData and 'temperatureProfile' in reportData['device'] and 'warningMax' in reportData['device']['temperatureProfile']):
        tempWarningMax = temperatureConversion(reportData['device']['temperatureProfile']['warningMax'], units)

    if('device' in reportData and 'temperatureProfile' in reportData['device'] and 'warningMin' in reportData['device']['temperatureProfile']):
        tempWarningMin = temperatureConversion(reportData['device']['temperatureProfile']['warningMin'], units)
    
    if (len(pings) > 0):
        for i in range(len(pings)):
            eventLogsforTimeStamp = None
            address = None
            eventData = None
            latitude = None
            longitude = None
            temperature = None
            dataTimeStamp = UTCtz.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(
                pings[i]['timeStamp'])).astimezone(tz).strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
            
            if('temperature' in pings[i] and pings[i]['temperature']):
                # if(units == 'F'):
                #     tempInF = temperatureConversion(pings[i]['temperature'], units)
                #     if tempInF:
                #         temperature = tempInF
                #     else:
                #         temperature = None
                # else:
                #     temperature = pings[i]['temperature']
                temperature = temperatureConversion(pings[i]['temperature'], units)
            else:
                temperature = None

            if temperature is not None:
                temperatureText = str(format(temperature,'.2f'))
                if((tempViolationMax is not None and (temperature > tempViolationMax)) or (tempViolationMin is not None and (temperature < tempViolationMin))):
                    temperatureText = '''<font size="8" color="red" > %s </font> '''%(temperature)
                elif(((tempViolationMax is not None  and temperature < tempViolationMax) and (tempWarningMax is not None and temperature > tempWarningMax)) or ((tempViolationMin is not None and temperature > tempViolationMin) and (tempWarningMin is not None and temperature < tempWarningMin))):
                    temperatureText = '''<font size="8" color="toColor('#d46d04')" > %s </font> '''%(temperature)
            else:
                temperatureText = '-'
            

            if ('timeStamp' in pings[i] and str(pings[i]['timeStamp']) and str(pings[i]['timeStamp']) in eventLogs and eventLogs[str(pings[i]['timeStamp'])]):
                eventLogsforTimeStamp = eventLogs[str(pings[i]['timeStamp'])]
            if(eventLogsforTimeStamp):
                eventData = getEventLogsWithImages(eventLogsforTimeStamp,units)
            else:
                eventData = '-'

            if('address' in pings[i] and 'locationReceivedPing' in pings[i] and pings[i]['locationReceivedPing'] == True):
                address = format(pings[i]['address'])
            else:
                address = '-'
            if ('lat' in pings[i] and 'locationReceivedPing' in pings[i] and pings[i]['locationReceivedPing'] == True):
                latitude = format(float(pings[i]['lat']),'.3f')
            else:
                latitude = '-'
            if('lng' in pings[i] and 'locationReceivedPing' in pings[i] and pings[i]['locationReceivedPing'] == True):
                longitude = format(float(pings[i]['lng']),'.3f')
            else:
                longitude = '-'
            if('locationReceivedPing' in pings[i] and pings[i]['locationReceivedPing'] == True):
                pingsData.append(
                [get_bold_para_table(dataTimeStamp),get_bold_para_table(temperatureText) , eventData, get_bold_para_table(latitude),get_bold_para_table(longitude),get_bold_para_table(address)])
            else:
                pingsData.append(
                [Paragraph(dataTimeStamp,styleN),Paragraph(temperatureText,styleN) , eventData, Paragraph(latitude, styleN),Paragraph(longitude, styleN),Paragraph(address, styleN)])

    table = LongTable(pingsData, repeatRows=2, colWidths=[73,47,205,42,43,158])
    table.setStyle(TableStyle([('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8),
                               ('SPAN', (0,0), (-1,0)),
                               ('LINEABOVE', (0, 0),(-1, -1), 1, colors.grey),
                               ('INNERGRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.25, colors.gray),
                               ('LINEBELOW', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.grey),
                               ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                               ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                               ]))

    return(table, Spacer(10, 20))

def run(reportData):
    output = BytesIO()
    doc = BaseDocTemplate(output,
                          showBoundary = 1,
                          leftMargin=pageMargin,
                          rightMargin=pageMargin,
                          topMargin=pageMargin,
                          bottomMargin=pageMargin,
                          pageSize=A4)

    elements = []

    frameT = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin,
                doc.width, doc.height, id='normal')
    
    frameWidth = (doc.width + 2 * inch - 120) / 3

    subFrameWidth = (doc.width + 2 * inch - 120)/2
    locationFrame1 = Frame(20, doc.bottomMargin,subFrameWidth, doc.height/4, id='loccol1' )
    locationFrame2 = Frame(30 + subFrameWidth, doc.bottomMargin, subFrameWidth,doc.height/4,id = 'loccol2')

    doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='OneCol', frames=frameT,onPage=foot2)])
    doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id = 'TwoCol', frames=[locationFrame1,locationFrame2],onPage=foot2)])

    title = getDocTitle(reportData)
    doc.title = title
    
    consignmentKey = reportData['companyInfo']['assetName']  if('companyInfo' in reportData and 'assetName' in reportData['companyInfo'] ) else 'Consignment'

    logo  = getLogo(reportData)
    [consignmentStatusLogo,consignmentStatus] = getConsignmentHealth(reportData, consignmentKey)
    statusTable = Table([[consignmentStatusLogo,consignmentStatus]], colWidths=[50,154])
    statusTable.setStyle(TableStyle([
                        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8.5),
                        ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(-1,-1),toColor('#edf6f6')),
                        # ('SPAN',(0,0),(-1,0)),
                        # ('ALIGN', (0,0),(-1,0),'CENTER'),
                        ('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                        # ('ALIGN', (1,1),(-1,-1),'LEFT'),
                        # ('ALIGN', (0,-1),(-1,-1),'RIGHT'),
                        # ('INNERGRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.25, colors.gray),
                        # ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
                                         
    ]))
    heading = Table([[logo,statusTable]], colWidths=[350,205])
    heading.setStyle(TableStyle([
                        ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'LEFT'),
                        ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                        # ('ALIGN', (0,0),(1,0),'CENTER')
                                         ]))
    
    elements.append(Spacer(20,10))
    elements.append(heading)

    companyName = reportData['companyName'] if 'companyName' in reportData else ''
    companyId = None
    if ('consignmentFromDb' in reportData and 'companyId' in reportData['consignmentFromDb'] and reportData['consignmentFromDb']['companyId'] == 'aeris'):
      companyId = reportData['consignmentFromDb']['companyId']

    units = 'C'
    if('companyInfo' in reportData and 'temperatureUnit' in reportData['companyInfo'] and reportData['companyInfo']['temperatureUnit']):
        units = reportData['companyInfo']['temperatureUnit']


    elements.append(Spacer(20,10))
    elements.append(getReportHeading(companyName, companyId,reportData))
    # elements.append(Spacer(20,5))

    elements.append(ConsignmentBar(reportData, consignmentKey))
    elements.append(Spacer(20,30))
    elements.extend(deviceInfoAndConfig(reportData,units, consignmentKey))
    elements.extend(getTripSummary(reportData,units))
    elements.extend(getViolationSummary(reportData))
    elements.append(Spacer(20,40))
    detailsTable = []
    if reportData and 'email' in reportData:
        detailsTable.append([get_bold_para("Report Generated By: "), Paragraph(reportData['email'], styleN)])
    if reportData and 'ip' in reportData:
        detailsTable.append([get_bold_para("IP Address: "), Paragraph(reportData['ip'], styleN)])
    table = Table(detailsTable,hAlign='LEFT', colWidths=[280,280])
    table.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('FONTSIZE',(0,0),(-1,-1),10)]))
    elements.append(table)
    elements.append(PageBreak())

    elements.append(Spacer(20,10))
    elements.extend(getTemperatureGraph(reportData,units))
    elements.append(Spacer(20,25))
    elements.extend(getMapsSection(reportData))
    elements.append(PageBreak())

    if('consignmentLogs' in reportData and len(reportData['consignmentLogs'])>0):
        consignmentLogsHeading = '''<para spaceAfter=15 spaceBefore=25><b><font size=11 color="toColor('#028081')">%s Edit Logs:</font></b></para>'''%(consignmentKey)
        consignmentLogsHeadingPara = Paragraph(consignmentLogsHeading, styles['Normal'])
        elements.append(consignmentLogsHeadingPara)
        elements.append(Spacer(20,10))
        elements.extend(getConsignmentLogs(reportData,units))
        elements.append(PageBreak())
    # elements.append(Spacer(1,1))
    pingsSectionHeading = '''<para spaceAfter=15 spaceBefore=25><b><font size=11 color="toColor('#028081')">Pings and Events Info:</font></b></para>'''
    pingsSectionHeadingPara = Paragraph(pingsSectionHeading, styles['Normal'])
    elements.append(pingsSectionHeadingPara)
    elements.append(Spacer(20,10))
    elements.extend(getEventsandPingsTable(reportData,units))

    doc.build(elements, canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)
    output.seek(0)
    return output
```

need help in resolving the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added the code. Can you please have a relook